# Редактирование текста с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно с помощью PHP удалить строки, в которых всего одна бува? И можно ли вообще? всего строк 88 тысяч

Comment: Для описанной задачи регулярки - это из пушки по воробьям. В PHP есть функция, возвращающая количество символов в строковой переменной (в просторечии - длину). Этого более чем достаточно. А если массив данных, который надо почистить, лежит в таблице БД, то задача ещё проще - удаление можно (и нужно!) выполнять средствами SQL-сервера, а роль PHP сведётся к отсылке на сервере одного простенького запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace("/^\S\n/m", "", $text);
```

[example](https://ideone.com/GZWkJj)